# Local MassTransit message storage in case of connection loss

Tags: masstransit

I am integrating several .Net modules using pub/sub messaging using RabbitMQ and MassTransit. Its important not to loose any message. When a module publishes a message it is supposed to be fire and forget action. In the moment the broker takes responsibility the publisher can fail and message will be delivered even much later.

I am trying to achieve the same behavior even when connection to broker is lost. I imagine a local persistent queue that will store the message(s) till they can be successfully delivered to the broker. The module can continue its operation meanwhile. If the module fails before it is able to deliver messages to the broker they stay stored locally. Once the module starts again and the connection to the broker is available, the stored messages are published to the broker. I am looking for an in-proc solution.

Does MassTransit support such a scenario out-of-the-box? Is there some 3rd party MT plugin that can do this?

Comment: There is nothing that works like this. Do you have a real problem or you are trying tio optimise for a fictious scenario? We process millions of messages per day with MT/RMQ and RMQ _never_ fails.

Comment: The real problem is a disconnected scenario. The requirement says that we have to finish processing even when connection to server fails and deliver acquired data after reconnecting. If RMQ is not installed on the same physical computer then any network problem is fatal.